# How to make a pagebreak that goes to the next double sided page?

Tags: page-breaking

I am writing a problem set for which the professor has mandated that each problem be submitted on a separate sheet (or sheets). To save some paper, I would like to print double-sided.

Thus my question: Is there a way to make LaTeX automatically break to the next new *sheet* of paper, so that in particular, whenever I page break it skips all the way to the next odd numbered page.

E.g. breaking on page 1 should start again on page 3 (so that the backside of page 1 is empty), but breaking on page 4 should just skip to page 5, since that will be a new sheet anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\cleardoublepage`.